# How Do I Change Rails 4 has_secure_password Presence Message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

**For reference**: Rails 4, bcrypt 3.1.7, and I'm using the simple_form gem

Within my model, I have this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :email,    presence: {message: 'You must provide an email'},
                         format: { with: /@/, message: 'Please enter a valid email' }
  validates :name,     presence: {message: 'You must enter your first name'}
  # TODO: Make validation message work
  validates :password, presence: {message: 'You must enter a password'},
                         length: {minimum: 8,
                                  message: 'Your password must contain at least 8 characters'}
end
```

Everything works as expected, except the presence validator for password. How do I go about changing the message to my message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the docs on `has_secure_password` here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html

As you can see, you can suppress the default validations:

`has_secure_password validations: false`

This should allow your custom validations for password to be used.

Note that you'll now need to explicitly add a password confirmation validation also.  Here's the one that's used in `has_secure_password` that you could use:

`validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true`

So with everything, your model would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password validations: false

  .
  .
  .

  validates :password, presence: {message: 'You must enter a password'},
                       length: {minimum: 8,
                       message: 'Your password must contain at least 8 characters'}
  validates_confirmation_of :password, allow_blank: true
end
```

**EDIT**

If you want to only change the message and still use the default validations that come with `has_secure_password`, you can edit your `en.yml` file:

*`config/locales/en.yml`*

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              blank: "You must enter a password"
```

Then, for `:password`, you will only need to add your minimum password validation, as that is not included with `has_secure_password`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  .
  .
  .

  validates :password, length: {
    minimum: 8,
    message: 'Your password must contain at least 8 characters'
  }
end
```

Comment: @Kieran: Have you had a chance to try this?  If it works, please mark this as an accepted answer. Or let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks!